# Find most likely fit for subgroup size and average density from product and supergroup size

Tags: data-visualization, predictive-models

I need to find the most likely sets of *group subset percent* and *frequency* for a *given result* having the *super group size*. Let me illustrate with an example.

Assume I have the following:

```
 Entity | Product | Price | Total Sales | Entity Customers
-----------------------------------------------------------
 BusA   | Yo-Yos  |    $6 |    $100,000 |         106,000
 BusB   | Yo-Yos  |    $4 |    $173,000 |          72,000
 BusC   | Yo-Yos  |    $7 |    $110,000 |          96,000
 BusD   | Yo-Yos  |    $9 |    $ 80,000 |          55,000
```

Having only this, my charge is to back into the most likely sets of:

1. Percent cohort buying yo-yo's out of total entity customers.
2. Average yo-yo's purchased at each entity's price.

When I model a function, I end up with:

```
f(percentBuyer, purchaseDensity) = {
  totalSales / (
    totalCust * percentBuyer * purchaseDensity
  )
}
```

`purchaseDensity` representing an average per buyer. I'm seeking for the best fits against a test. A sample set:

```
[ 5%, 1],[ 5%, 2],[ 5%, 3],
[10%, 1],[10%, 2],[10%, 3],
[15%, 1],[15%, 2],[15%, 3]
... et cetera ...
```

And so on. My sense is that I can graph these against the `Price` and `Total Sales` in the different rows and which values per set fit best the `Price` at that entity, I'll have my best fit.

I know I could be getting something fundamentally wrong up to this point; I hope not. The issue I run into is I'm unsure how to graph this where the best fits can be determined and a range for best fit be developed that present a reasonable prediction of characteristic fluctuation.

Where do I go from here? Go back? Am I overlooking a direct way to handle this type of concern?

---

<sup>Note, this is **not** homework; it is related to a project I am assigned at work, and involves a risk management cost-benefit depiction. If there are more appropriate tags for this, please feel free to edit them in.</sup>

Comment: Does the `Total sales` column represent the total revenue of each entity from yo-yos? So `BusA` sold $100,000/6=16,667$ yo-yos? Or is it the total sales of all products for that entity?

Comment: @Aniko - Yes, that would be the total sales for the yo-yo's only.